# TSX React - How to index JSON API Data with multiple JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

I am trying to use `useFetch` to get API data and index to get a specific value.

This is the current code:

```
const { isLoading, error, data } = useFetch("https://public-api.solscan.io/account/tokens?account=C9XzDbZrZkJ75EvEeb641PQ5Q9kDiN2nFugdyAXqGip1");
  const dataStarsStaked = JSON.stringify(data, ["0", "tokenAddress", "tokenAmount", "uiAmount"], 0);
```

which returns `data`:

```
[{"tokenAddress":"4q5UBXJxE91BZKX548qhU8i5QBWvZdXzS3RZwfTgLQda","tokenAmount":{"uiAmount":253847.899902}},{"tokenAddress":"HCgybxq5Upy8Mccihrp7EsmwwFqYZtrHrsmsKwtGXLgW","tokenAmount":{"uiAmount":6864373.022357}},{"tokenAddress":"HkNK7BL5pSUUzc6ns1mHW5JnzbSG4S9u2QdR3cUuyzSa","tokenAmount":{"uiAmount":678}}]
```

I am trying to get the value of uiAmount of `tokenAddress: HCgybxq5Upy8Mccihrp7EsmwwFqYZtrHrsmsKwtGXLgW`. How do I do this? I am not sure how to index this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can search the data array:

```
data.find(x => x.tokenAddress === "HCgybxq5Upy8Mccihrp7EsmwwFqYZtrHrsmsKwtGXLgW");
```

To get rid of the typescript errors, you need to define types (use something similar to this, but change `any[]` to the array of object types the api is returning):

```
interface YourFetchResult {
   data: any[];
   isLoading: boolean;
   error?: string;
}

const { isLoading, error, data }: FetchResult = useFetch(...)
```

Comment: Okay. I am getting x is of implicit any type error and data is of type unknown.

Comment: are you using typescript?

Comment: Yes, I am using typescript

Comment: Then to get rid of those errors you need to define the types

Comment: Okay, but what is the type of `data` in this case? Is there a JSON type?

Comment: Create an `interface` for the return type of `data` so you can define what each value is in the array of objects.

Comment: Im confused how I would do that exactly for data, could you show me?

Comment: I just added an example of how to use an interface, would recommend doing more research as it is a basis for the benefits of using typescript.

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply a for loop and have a condition that detects the string see below

```
  let x  = [{"tokenAddress":"4q5UBXJxE91BZKX548qhU8i5QBWvZdXzS3RZwfTgLQda","tokenAmount":{"uiAmount":253847.899902}},{"tokenAddress":"HCgybxq5Upy8Mccihrp7EsmwwFqYZtrHrsmsKwtGXLgW","tokenAmount":{"uiAmount":6864373.022357}},{"tokenAddress":"HkNK7BL5pSUUzc6ns1mHW5JnzbSG4S9u2QdR3cUuyzSa","tokenAmount":{"uiAmount":678}}]
  
  for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if(x[i].tokenAddress==="HCgybxq5Upy8Mccihrp7EsmwwFqYZtrHrsmsKwtGXLgW") {
      console.log(x[i].tokenAmount)
    }
  
  }
```

Comment: Because its a string it doesnt detect "tokenAddress" property or "tokenAmount" property. Hmm. Is there anyway I can convert it?